# Windows Phone 7.1 XNA project swapped x and y coordinates

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-7.1, coordinate

I created a Windows Phone XNA game from the Visual Studio Templates using C#. 
For some reason when a draw an object at a coordinate on the screen my (0,0) coordinate is on the right and the x and y coordinates are swapped.

Here is what i have (everything else is as the template)

```
 Vector2 pos; // My objects
 Texture2D pic; // My objects

 pos = new Vector2(300, 100); //in My LoadContent Menthod
 pic = Content.Load<Texture2D>("line"); //in My LoadContent Menthod

 spriteBatch.Begin(); // in my draw method
 spriteBatch.Draw(pic, pos, Color.White);
 spriteBatch.End();
```

My object is drawn at (100,300) with right top as (0,0)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Turn your phone 180 degrees.

Comment: Haha - honestly, this is just how the coordinate system in Windows phone works. What orientation are you programming for?

Comment: Portrait. Thing is I have another project on a different PC. Same code but the coordinate system is fine

Comment: Have you (somehow) changed the default orientation for that PC? Is it a laptop? If so, does it have an accelerometer?

Comment: Well I tried on the emulator on my PC and the coordinates were screwed up. Then i tried on my work laptop they were bad again. And i ran the app on my windows phone as well and there it was wrong as well. So my only guess is that it is something with the code.

Comment: Try a sample application - You'll probably find that this is intended behaviour.

Comment: Well i find out how to solve this. One of my projects works fine so i as long as i change it and dont create a new project i will be able to work.